# Hadoop streaming how to multiply matrix by vector when they're stored in many files

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, matrix-multiplication, hadoop-streaming

I have a matrix like:

```
1,1,2
2,3,4
6,4,6
1,2,4
3,6,3
4,6,2
4,5,8
3,4,4
```

and vector

```
1,3
4,5
5,4
6,2
```

They're stored in two different files. I need to multiply them by column. The matrix is of body M(i,j,v), where i is row number, j column number and v is a value. The vector is of body V(j,v).

I wrote a mapper

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

# class to store matrix records
class MatrixRecord(object):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.i= None
        self.j= None
        self.v= None

# class to store vector records
class VectorRecord(object):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.j= None
        self.v= None

# lists to store objects
listOfMatrixRecords = []
listOfVectorRecords = []

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace and split
    splittedLine = line.strip().split(",")  

    # if it's matrix element - body looks like
    # 1,3,6
    if(len(splittedLine) == 3):
        x = MatrixRecord();
        x.i = splittedLine[0]
        x.j = splittedLine[1]
        x.v = splittedLine[2]
        listOfMatrixRecords.append(x) #add it to matrix records list
    #if it's vector element - body looks like
    # 2,4
    else: 
        y = VectorRecord();
        y.j = splittedLine[0]
        y.v = splittedLine[1]
        listOfVectorRecords.append(y) #add it to vector records list

#get matrix records and multiply them by vector values
vectorPosition = {record.j for record in listOfVectorRecords} #gets j properties of objects from vector
matrixPosition = {record.j for record in listOfMatrixRecords} #gets j properties of objects from matrix

for duplicate in vectorPosition & matrixPosition: #checks for duplicates between matrix and vector
    for x in listOfMatrixRecords:
        if x.j == duplicate:    # if there's a duplicate, it means that we must multiply
            for y in listOfVectorRecords:
                if y.j == x.j:
                    x.v = int(x.v) * int(y.v);

#return result to stdout, reducer will take it as input
for x in listOfMatrixRecords:
    print ('%s\t%s' % (x.i,x.v))
```

but it works only if everything is stored in one input file, not many, because for each file the new mapper is created and therefore

```
listOfMatrixRecords = []
listOfVectorRecords = []
```

never contain all matrix / vector records.

Is there a way to write custom shuffle method for hadoop streaming perhaps?

I launch hadoop like this:

```
hadoop jar "D:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\tools\lib\hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.jar" -mapper "python D:\map.py" -reducer "python D:\reducer.py" -input /input/* -output /output
```